i try to logout from my dashboard components, it stuck on dashboard with loading and all the dashboard content remove
Here is my code to get the dashboard form backend using useEffect and then the handler to handle the logout button
After few time if I reload the page then its redirected the login page.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import axios from 'axios';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) {
      navigate('/login', { replace: true });
      return;
    }

    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/auth/dashboard', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, 
          },
        });
        setUser(response.data); 
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.response?.status === 401) {
          toast.error('Please login to access the dashboard');
          navigate('/login', { replace: true });
        } else {
          toast.error('Failed to fetch user data');
        }
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchUserData();
  }, [navigate, token]); 

  const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    setUser(null);
    toast.success('Logged out successfully!');

    navigate('/login', { replace: true });
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center min-h-screen">
        <p>Loading...</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (!user) {
    return null; // Don't render the dashboard if no user data is available
  }

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen bg-background text-foreground p-6">
      {/* Header Section */}
      <div className="flex justify-between items-center mb-6">
        <div>
          <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold">Welcome, {user.name}</h1>
          <p className="text-muted-foreground">Rank: #{user.rank} | Problems Solved: {user.problemsSolved}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center">
          <img
            src={user.avatar || 'https://via.placeholder.com/50'}
            alt="User Avatar"
            className="w-16 h-16 rounded-full border border-border mr-4"
          />
          <Button onClick={handleLogout} className="bg-destructive hover:bg-destructive-400 text-white">
            Logout
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Progress and Stats */}
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-6">
        {/* Progress Overview */}
        <div className="bg-card rounded-lg shadow-md p-4">
          <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold mb-4">Progress</h2>
          <div className="h-6 bg-muted rounded-full overflow-hidden">
            <div className="h-full bg-primary" style={{ width: `${(user.problemsSolved / 100) * 100}%` }}></div>
          </div>
          <p className="text-sm text-muted-foreground mt-2">{user.problemsSolved}% Problems Solved</p>
        </div>

        {/* Quick Links */}
        <div className="bg-card rounded-lg shadow-md p-4">
          <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold mb-4">Quick Links</h2>
          <ul className="space-y-2">
            <li>
              <a href="/problems" className="text-primary hover:underline">
                Solve Problems
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/contests" className="text-primary hover:underline">
                Join Contests
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/settings" className="text-primary hover:underline">
                Account Settings
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        {/* Statistics */}
        <div className="bg-card rounded-lg shadow-md p-4">
          <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold mb-4">Statistics</h2>
          <p>Total Submissions: {user.totalSubmissions}</p>
          <p>Accepted: {user.accepted}</p>
          <p>Accuracy: {user.accuracy}%</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Recent Activity */}
      <div className="mt-6 bg-card rounded-lg shadow-md p-4">
        <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold mb-4">Recent Activity</h2>
        <ul className="divide-y divide-border">
          {user.recentActivity.map((activity, index) => (
            <li className="py-2" key={index}>
              <p>{activity.problemTitle} - {activity.status}</p>
              <p className="text-sm text-muted-foreground">{activity.timestamp}</p>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;


After click on logout button -

user should redirect to login page but it lstuck on dashboard with a Loading...

user should not stuck on dashboard with loading... screen, user should be redirect to login
if you want to check full code here is the github repo link - https://github.com/SamratPandey/ByteRunners.git
fell free to any suggestions

What dashboard are you referring to when a user logs out? I believe we'll need to see a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with to help with any specific issues you have with it. I invite you you also take the [tour] and review Help/How to Ask to learn additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

I a simple dashboard component of my project

Ok, can you show us what that is... in code? We need to see the specific and relevant code that you are referring to and working with in the post. The tour and help page I referred you to explain how to use this site.

ok, i will update it

I notice your Dashboard component code in the post doesn't match the Dashboard component code in your repo. Please also [edit] the post to share an accurate [mcve] of the code you are using. FWIW the code in your repo seems correct and redirects to "/" home page which doesn't appear to be a protected route page or apply any logic to redirect back to "/dashboard" and get a user stuck there.

I just done all the update and update the repo also

Ok, so which is the code you need help with? This post has an incomplete [mcve] and your repo appears to have correct as far as I can tell. The last update in your repo was two days ago. Are you sure you just updated it? Are you updating some other non-main branch?

I provide the code that i need to help with
